# how to use psql 'distinct on' with hibernate createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to translate my pgsql query to hibernate query.

**Query:**

`select distinct on (domain) * from usersreport where id = 'testOrg' and date = '2020-11-24 00:00:00.0';`

how to convert this query to the HQL query.

Comment: See related part of hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-distinct).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't support a `distinct on` query.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to get the same result as of 'distinct on' query?

Comment: `distinct on` is often misused when you should be using `group by`. It makes your query more complex, though.